# Выборка значения из List<object> по имени атрибута переданного строкой

Tags: c#

Есть классический List<объектов>.
Он возвращает мне значения поля Name3.

тестовый пример

```
    class Test1
    {
        public string Name1 { get; set; }
        public string Name2 { get; set; }
        public string Name3 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Test1> ltest1 = new List<Test1>();
            ltest1.Add(new Test1() { Name1 = "n1", Name2 = "n1", Name3 = "n3", });
            ltest1.Add(new Test1() { Name1 = "n2", Name2 = "n2", Name3 = "n2", });
            ltest1.Add(new Test1() { Name1 = "n3", Name2 = "n3", Name3 = "n3", });
            string res = ltest1.Where(w => w.Name1 == "n2").FirstOrDefault().Name3.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }   
    }
```

Мне нужно изменить выборку так чтобы он возвращал значение поля заданного строкой.
ну что то типа

```
string res = ltest1.Where(w => w.Name1 == "n2").FirstOrDefault().("Name3").ToString();
```

Список полей большой и мне нужно выбирать значения по полям заданные строками.
Как это сделать?

Сейчас сделано так что я возвращаю сам объект test и беру нужное поле test.Name3.
Это работает.
Но у меня есть выборки как из list так и из DataTable
В DataTable возвращает интерфейс связи с внешней системой. И там полей 200+
и таблиц с десяток.
Из DataTable выбираем как например Field(columnName)
Хотелось бы как то написать единый метод выборки нужных значений.
Мне удобней передавать имя column строкой.
Проблема в том что я не знаю как в моем случае list выбрать поле передав колонку строкой.

Вопрос больше академический.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать рефлексию.

```
var res = string.Empty;
var propertyName = "Name3";
var item = ltest1.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name1 == "n2");
if (item != null)
{
    res = typeof(Test1).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(item) as string;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.